# C# generlized order by

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a generalized method for sorting any kind of list by any kind of variable.

E.g. I have a Student and a Class entity:

```
Order(studentList, s => s.Name, desc)
Order(classList, s => s.ClassName, desc)
```

I have tried to create a private method for doing this:

```
private List<T> Order<T, TKey>(List<T> listToOrder, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sortKey, bool desc)
{
   return desc ? listToOrder.OrderByDescending(sortKey) : listToOrder.OrderBy(sortKey)
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Any ideas how I can achieve this? Will edit the answer if it's not sufficient enough.

Comment: What is not working? Do you have an exception?

Comment: Your method seems to be assuming `T` is a list as well as a type parameter... and the `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` methods don't return lists, they return sequences. Next, "this obviously doesn't work" isn't as descriptive as providing a full description of what you're seeing. Finally, I'd suggest using just `Func<T, TKey>` rather than expression trees here, unless you really need expression trees for some reason you haven't told us.

Comment: It works without Expression! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I can't see any advantage in creating this function at all as all it does is calling either `OrderByDescending` or `OrderBy`. Apart from this I cannot see why your code should not work. Please be more specific on your problem.

Comment: Why are you using `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` instead of simply `Func<T, TKey>`? In general `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` is used when you have an `IQueryable<T>`, but you don't have one of those.

Comment: I'd also suggest you change `bool desc` to `enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }`. Then your code is readable. `Order(list, x => x.Name, false)` is less readable than `Order(list, x => x.Name, SortDirection.Descending)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Student` & `Class` values are collected, you can try to write an extension method

1. return type might be `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` which type from `OrderBy` & `OrderByDescending`.
2. you might not need to use `Expression` just use delegate `Func<T, TKey>` will be enough

as below

```
public static class MyExtesion{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Order<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source,Func<T, TKey> sortKey, bool desc)
    {
        return desc ? source.OrderByDescending(sortKey) : source.OrderBy(sortKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understand is correct, try this :

```
    public static List<T> Order<T>(List<T> listToOrder, Func<T, int> sortFunc, bool desc)
    {
        return desc ?
            listToOrder.OrderByDescending(x => sortFunc(x)).ToList() : listToOrder.OrderBy(x => sortFunc(x)).ToList();
    }
```

Following is test codes:

```
var arr1 = new int[] {1,-1,2,-2,0,3,-3};
var result = LogHelper.Order(arr1.ToList(),x=>x*x,false);
```

Just log them.

[image]